# Abap table creation, combination reference table/field does not exist. What could be wrong?

Tags: abap, activation, sap-erp, sap-data-dictionary

I'm trying to activate my table in the SAP system.
As you may tell, i'm only a beginner, anyway, the error log:

> TABL ZAVG_SO_OO was not activated Check table ZAVG_SO_OO
> (VARDELEAN/17.07.12/17:27) ZAVG_SO_OO-NETWR (combination reference
> table/field VBAP-NETWR does not exist)
> Table ZAVG_SO_OO must be created in the database
> Check on table ZAVG_SO_OO resulted in errors

The vbap-netwr message is confusing me. Obviously table VBAP has a field NETWR. The rest i don't really know what to think of.

Any clues?

Comment: what data element did you assign to `ZAVG_SO_OO-NETWR`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget for currency and quantity fields like NETWR you need a reference table and reference field. Go into SE11, put in VBAP, click on the currency/quantity field tab and scroll down to your NETWR. Hit F1 to get a nice description of what this field is doing for you. Your custom table needs these references as well. Hope this leads you in the right direction.